How do I get the actual directory behind /$bunfs/root
I am trying to get the directory in which my executable is located so I can access certain directories relative to it.  When I do something like
const executionDirectory = path.resolve(import.meta.dir), I get /$bunfs/root
And there are no files in this directory.
const executionDirectory = __dirname gives me the source directory but not where the executable is located.

The solution I found is
const executionDirectory = process.execPath.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')
This seems to do the trick.  If there is a better way - please let me know.
